# nextjs with express and csurf: invalid csrf token when api call in getInitialProps server-side

Tags: express, csrf, next.js

My setup works fine apart from that special flow:

1) On my express server I have a route /bookings which sends back a new csrf token.

2) In my Nextjs bookings.js page in getInitialProps(), I use that csrf token to call "api/user/bookings" on the server  (which is also csrf protected).

3) But I get an invalid csrf Token exception from the server.

I think this should work because I created a new csrf token in the first request and use it in the consecutive api request.

Here is the relevant code:

[image: server.js]

[image: bookings.js]

[image: fetch.js]

Comment: I don't believe calling `req.csrfToken()` updates the token inside of the session. So when you say "On my express server I have a route /bookings which sends back a new csrf token" it _does_ return a new token but the server does not retain it (again, because it isn't saved back into the session). This may be a piece of evidence to work off of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the meantime I completely workaround the process to not be dependant on this issue.